# Nasty SSL certificate error occurs in Rails controller, but not in console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, openssl

This error just keeps popping up at different times. It is absolutely maddening, and productivity-sapping.

This is `rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392` and `Rails 3.2.13`, and `Pow`.

In the console, this command works:

```
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request(request)}
```

The exact same command, when accessed from a controller, FAILS with this error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I have seen ***numerous*** posts and answers on SO about the error. There are scores of answers, because the technology stack used is so brittle because of the many moving parts and many, many different locations of certificate files. However, I have yet to see exactly why this works in the Rails console, while it fails from the Rails controller. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a mystery why this worked in the console and not in the controller. But there were so many moving parts, I decided to scrap the original rvm install and start over.

Many people that have had their Mac environments for a while have used MacPorts in the past. Some, like me, have moved on to Homebrew. But I maintain both, because there are some libraries I can't get on Homebrew that I can only get from MacPorts. I try to avoid building from source as much as humanly possible, because I have gone into dependency hell like that in the past and I need to rely on people smarter than me.

What I did to solve the problem was to set rvm to exclusively use Homebrew, something I had never done before:

```
rvm autolibs homebrew
```

This first required a Homebrew update:

```
brew update
```

but it will tell you if you need to do that, or do it for you automatically.

Then I did:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

This built `Ruby 1.9.3-p429` from source, since no binaries were available.

I had OpenSSL installed in a couple of different places (MacPorts and Homebrew homes) so that may have been part of my original problem.

The installation went off without a hitch. I recreated my original gemset under 1.9.3 and created the appropriate `.rvmrc` file.

Now the `SSL_connect` errors are gone.